# Generate word document from bytes in the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, dynamic, ms-word

I am developing an spring boot web application (Java) that automates document generation. One issue that I am facing is I have a a word document template in the database and when a user wishes to generate a document, I want to create a new document using that stored template. So Is there a way to generate a word document from a template whose bytes are stored in the database. Also storing I wish to store this document back to the database by getting it bytes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be word document has a template, which you can open from word application, you can't use this application with Spring Boot. Do you have any code with it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now I am doing something like opening the template stored with in my directory and adding the values to the template. This creates a file in my directory which I then open and upload it to the database. I used the code from this website: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/3-ways-to-generate-word-documents-from-templates-in-java/

Comment: So run a query and save it as a file. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per the link you posted in comment, you're using free spire.doc library. You can:

- First, convert bytes to stream, call Document.loadFromStream method provided by the library to load the template from stream.
- Second, after filling in data, save the document back to stream use Document.saveToStream method.
- Finally, convert the stream to bytes.

The following is an example (haven't tested it yet), you can give it a try.

```
    byte[] inputBytes = yourBytes;
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes);
    Document document = new Document();
    document.loadFromStream(inputStream, FileFormat.Docx);

    //do something
    //......

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.saveToStream(outputStream, FileFormat.Docx_2013);
    byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
```